# Python 2.7 TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str

Tags: encoding, xlrd

I try to open an excel sheet with Python and xlrd but I still have the following error

> error in open_workbook:
>
> f = open(filename, "rb")
>
> TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str.

This is my code:

```
FILE =  tkFileDialog.askopenfile()
string=FILE.read()
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(string)
```

Please what's wrong? Thanks a lot

Comment: `print repr(filename)` and show us what you get.

Comment: It looks like you have null bytes in the file you're reading to get the file name.

Comment: print repr(FILE) you mean?? I get:<open file u'C:/Users/pmarguer/Documents/PM/FSM1_GSM_List_Parameters_V3.01_AI.xlsm', mode 'r' at 0x02A46C28>

Comment: Yes indeed when I display it, many \0x00 are present in that file but  what to do ? It should open anyway?

Comment: Fix the file you're reading the filename from. If it was generated by another program, fix that program too.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean fix the excel sheet ? but I think I am going a wrong way. Indeed I use a a string string to read the file and use open_workbook but the first argument of this API is a pathname not a string. I have used a string because when I do wb = xlrd.open_workbook(FILE) i hace the following error:TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Comment: Not the excel sheet! The string you pass to `xlrd.open_workbook` is coming from some file. Fix *that* file.

Comment: Ok I found my problem, I was using askopenfile()instead of askopenfilename()... sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `askopenfilename` instead of `askopenfile` unless you are really passing a file and not its name.

```
FILE =  tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
string = FILE.read()
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(string)
```